# SSIS Oracle Provider not showing in Toolbox

Tags: oracle, visual-studio, ssis, ssis-2012

First Post :)

I am using Visual studio 2019 (SSIS) but for some reason, the Oracle Provider for OLE DB is not showing in the source or destination. I have downloaded the latest ODAC for 64 and 32 bit as well as the ODT for the latest VS and none of these work. I have restarted my pc thinking this would need to synch but still nothing shows.

Am I missing a step perhaps?

Comment: Go to Extensions > Manage Extensions > Online, and search in the search bar for Oracle Provider. Let me know if you find it there

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

Right click on the Connection Manager > New Connection Manager

[image]

Choose OLEDB froma  list of connections and then press Add:

[image]

Press New and at the top drop-down menu where you choose the Provider search for Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle

[image]

You are now good to go.

Comment: Hi Francesco, This option does indeed exist but doesn't connect me to oracle even though I am successfully able to connect to oracle from an excel ODBC connection, So I noticed the youtube tutorials always point to an "Oracle Provider for OLE DB" so I thought perhaps this could connect me?

For example:
https://static.squarespace.com/static/52d1b75de4b0ed895b7e7de9/52d2ce19e4b004fe15b16415/52d2ce1ae4b004fe15b16945/1346594326103/Windows-Live-Writer-8894b0c59213_652F-

https://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2012/9/2/resolving-missing-records-in-ssis-from-oracle-source.html

Comment: However getting this option under source and destinations is the challenge i am experiencing

Comment: You will never be able to see them in the source/destination menu. You will only see the Oracle OLE DB in  the Connection Manager as I showed you in the picture

Comment: Under the connection manager where it says Provider: Native OLE DB\ It doesn't show the option of Oracle Provider for OLEDB. It does indeed show MS OLE DB Provider for Oracle however when connecting to that, It doesn't accept my connection and creds. I've tested on ODBC Connection Manager and all was validated im not sure what i am doing wrong perhaps?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help you till there. The one I showed you is the only Oracle OLEDB connector that I know. Try to ask your colleagues.